# File_get_contents and XML Not Loading Through Directories

Tags: php, xml

So basically I've been trying to edit an XML file but it is not opening. When I use file_get_contents it only responds with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

When really it contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<game><isOnline>1</isOnline><port>04714</port></game>
```

Note that this XML file is in a far directory:

```
C:\Users\xorex\Documents\Spirit-master\config
```

and my php file is loaded from

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\x\api
```

However, when I change the location of my XML file and put it in the same directory as the PHP file, it functions normally. Please help me. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$file = "C:/Users/xorex/Documents/Spirit-master/config5.xml";
die(file_get_contents($file));
$info = simplexml_load_file(file_get_contents($file));
$info->isOnline = $online;
$info->asXML($file);
?>
```

P.S. I put the die in there just to check what I get as a response. Sorry if this is a stupid question but I tried everything and the config file MUST be in that directory.

Comment: Check the config5.xml again at the location it is at. Also view source of the Skript you are running it might hide the xml just as it hides html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you file is in the wrong dir

instead of

```
"C:/Users/xorex/Documents/Spirit-master/config5.xml";
```

should be

```
"C:/Users/xorex/Documents/Spirit-master/config/config5.xml";
```

Comment: I feel so dumb oh my god. Thank you  so much